# SQL Azure Databases Located in Multiple Countries

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I am investigating using Azure/SQL Azure to migrate from a number of 'on-premises' database servers to a number of SQL Azure databases, our issue is that:

1.) Traffic needs to be secured using VPN.
2.) Each database needs to be physically located in the country from which it is being accessed.
3.) These databases need to communicate with each other via scheduled job using SSIS (currently we use the company VPN and each database can talk to all the others.

After searching around I am somewhat sure we can do 1.) but 2.) and 3.) are unknowns to me and no amount of searching I do can find what I need. I presume I am searching the wrong phrase.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Traffic needs to be secured using VPN

This is possible. Have a look into the Virtual Network offering - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/virtual-network

2.) Each database needs to be physically located in the country from which it is being accessed.

Depends on what countries you are supporting. Windows Azure currently has Data Centers in the following locations.

- Asia East (Hong Kong)
- Asia Southeast (Singapore)
- Europe North (Ireland)
- Europe West (Netherlands)
- USA North Central (Illinois)
- USA South Central (Texas)
- USA East (Virginia)
- USA West (California)

3.) These databases need to communicate with each other via scheduled job using SSIS

SQL Azure supports connectivity via SSIS Packages (for querying ,data import/export etc...) but there's currently no hosted SSIS Option for Azure. You would need an on-premises or Azure VM Hosted regular SQL Server instance to host & co-ordinate your package schedules between your various SQL Azure databases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into the virtual network link. Are there are any other ways to have communication between our different azure databases once they in the cloud without having to use our on premises databases? We want to synchronise all data from each facility into a single database and I guess thought that once it was in the cloud then we could communicate up there.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Centers are not located on every country so the only time you can satisfy #2 is if there's a data center located in that country from which you are trying to access it from. (e.g., you are trying to access from Singapore, there's a DC in Singapore, so #2 can be satisfied.)

Comment: Thanks for the that. I did read something about a DC in China because I think we would really need that. Searching around seems to indicate they have made a deal with a company called 21Vianet in Shanghai?

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to achieve with the VPN? the DB servers for SQL Databases on Windows Azure provide Firewall Whitelisting : if the ip isn't in the list , it doesn't allow access ...

second : for the scheduled SSIS? what do you wantto do with it ? just sync? or ETL of somekind?

Either Way: my guess is that you think SQL Databases are SQL Servers like you have them on prem ... do be advised that this is not the case! SQL Database are a modified TDS like you know them on SQL Sevrer but with some limitation (but with the advantages of scallability and cloud model)

if you're looking into SSIS as a synchronisation mechanism it would rather advice you to take a look to SQL Database Data Sync here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/sql-databases/getting-started-w-sql-data-sync/ and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh667301.aspx